# How to prevent span from growing with content

Tags: html, css

I have a div and inside a link element
 before a span element which must stay on the same line. the user can edit the text inside the span. however when the text gets too long, the span jump to a new line, leaving the  in the first line alone. how do I prevent this?

So when I input text like "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" or "Aasdasd asdasd asdasdasd asdasd", the span jumps into a new line and now the div takes double the space as before

**EDIT2: I added a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pv4ncqvr/).** What I want is that "Some Icon" and the span text stay on the same line!

edit: this is my code:

```css
.slide {
background-color: red;
    height: 100px;
width: 100px;
}

.roundCorners {
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide roundCorners">
<i>some icon </i>
<span id="slide-name">That nasdasdasdame</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

Comment: can you provide an example of your code? it helps to understand your issue

Comment: @MJB Please post the generated HTML, and the related CSS (if any), rather than the template...

Comment: the generated html is exactly how it looks in the template. I removed the unnecessary stuff

Comment: @MJB *"div and inside a link element before a span element"* - where/which is the *link* element..?

Comment: can you give us jsfiddle?

Comment: I updated it with a fiddle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.slide {
  display: inline-block;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

DEMO: https://jsbin.com/yekohi/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: works beautiful. Do you care to explain why it works? Thank you very much anyway!

Comment: @MJB `width:100%`. The `<span>` has more then enough space to render the content.

Comment: Thanks. It works because that is the css that does single line overflow ellipsis cross browser, it needs all those styles to swing it. Needs a width, even if it's 100%. http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, You can use `white-space: nowrap` to prevent the text from breaking into a new line.

For example,

```css
.slide {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide roundCorners"> <i>some icon </i>
  <span id="slide-name">That nasdasdasdame</span>

</div>
```

Comment: Just apply it to `.slide`. This does it right: `.slide{white-space:nowrap;}`

Comment: @TJ: you initially hinted to use it on the span, that's why I said "doesn't work"

Comment: @MJB Yea that's fine, I didn't test it while posting because the fiddle was not there at that time ;)

Answer (score 0):

tyr this using `table-cell`:

```
.slide {
    background-color: red;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

i, #slide-name {
    display: table-cell;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shiralizadeh/pv4ncqvr/2/)